# Raspberry isn't starting

Tags: boot, sd-card

I'm having problems with my Raspberry Pi (2 different Raspberry Pi's actually).

I wrote the Raspbian IMG on SD using `dd` on my Mac and Win32DiskImager on Windows.

I've downloaded it twice and I've also used two different SD cards, but neither start.

One of them had an old version (very old) of Raspbian and with that the Raspberry started correctly. What could be the problem?
I know that both cards are compatible with Raspberry.

Just the red LED is switched on, while the green LED "OK" blinks for a while and than switches off.

PS: Using NOOBS instead of Raspbian I have no problem. How it is possible?

Comment: Did you check the video? Are you using HDMI?

Comment: Yes I m using HDMI, How should I check?

Comment: @WillianPaixao probably means if the monitor gets a blank/black signal or goes to sleep where the latter means that the startup proces hasn't even gone to the point where the HDMI output is done.

Comment: First off, the green LED is a good thing. Second, its possible that video output is being sent to AV and not HDMI. Have you tested both video interfaces?

Comment: Can you ssh the Pi?

Comment: Could be an old image of Raspbian with firmware that has problems with your particular SD cards.

Comment: I've just downloaded the image, and no since it is the first startup I can't ping raspberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test another SD card.  Visually verify that the SD card slot doesn't have a broken solder joint or pin.  There is also a switch that is closed when an SD card is inserted also, make sure the SD card is seated tightly enough to close the switch.  If an SD card is not detected the RPi will not boot.  Also [check this reference](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) for more information.

Comment: I've already done all this things

Comment: Have you read the reference at all?  There is a section on flash patterns for the light if you have a Micron processor.  Please check this reference and check the light pattern on the Pi that will not start.